# Ruby or Rails: PG Data Query Error,

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, type-conversion, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to update a few records based on a user entered string - it won't let me and produces this error:

```
PGError: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type boolean: "ian"
LINE 1: UPDATE "subjects" SET treatment_group = 'ian' AND pref_rand ...
```

I double checked the type from the rails console:

```
Subject.column_hash["treatment_group"].type
=> :string
```

And the input method is:

```
Group Name: <%= text_field_tag(:treatment_group_name) %>
```

Finally, within the controller I have this logic:

```
@group_to_randomize = Subject.where("study_site = ? AND treatment_group is null", params[:site_input].to_i).order("created_at ASC").limit(params[:group_size_input].to_i)

      flash[:notice] = "We are at the database level. #{@group_to_randomize.inspect}"
      if params[:treatment_group_name] != '' and params[:site_input] != '' and params[:group_size_input] != ''
        @group_to_randomize.update_all(["treatment_group = ? AND pref_rand = ?", params[:treatment_group_name, @treatment.to_i])
        flash[:notice] = "Subjects randomized, and assigned to group #{params[:treatment_group_name]}"
      else
        flash[:notice] = "Nothing saved, please fill in the form completely."
      end
```

**So that it's easier to read, the error stems from this line:**

```
@group_to_randomize.update_all(["treatment_group = ? AND pref_rand = ?", params[:treatment_group_name], @treatment.to_i])
```

So I can't figure out why it thinks the input is a boolean, and why it won't save as a string anyway. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because of syntax error, modify this line

```
@group_to_randomize.update_all(treatment_group:params[:treatment_group_name], pref_rand: @treatment.to_i)
```